# Side effects if running Git commands while not in the root folder

Tags: git, version-control, repository

When running Git commands from command line do the commands need to always be executed while in the root folder of the repository (the folder containing the `.git` folder) or can be executed from anywhere inside the repository folder?

The commands work but I'm worried they might have side effects.

Are there Git commands that behave differently when executed from some sub-folder as opposed to executing from the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to run a git command from a subdirectory of the root of the repository. Git tries to find the `.git` directory which is located in the root directory of the respository, which is where it stores all the bookkeeping information. If it can't find it, it searches the parent directory, and the grandparent directory, and so on until it find a directory which contains a `.git` directory.